# Why child process not getting exited before parent process calls wait() function?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, wait

I'm working on c program which uses `fork()` and `wait()` calls, firstly I created five child processes and then I called `wait()` for five times. Whenever I execute the program it prints the same child process id in the second for loop which is displayed from the first for loop. The child processes were never getting exited before the wait() function is getting called. Why is this happening? Why the `cpid` is always printing the exact child process id which were displayed before?

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main( )
{
    int child_pids[5];
    int i;
    printf("PARENT ID: %d \n", getpid());
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        if(fork()==0) {
            printf("child(pid): %d of parent(pid): %d \n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        int cpid=wait(NULL);
        printf("parent (pid): %d waited for child(pid): %d \n",getpid(),cpid);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If there are any mistakes in my way of asking questions, please comment below

Comment: "*Why the cpid is always printing the exact child process id which were displayed before?*" the parent waits for its children, the processes it created. What would you expect to see differently?

Comment: since the ```wait(NULL)``` will get called only after the creation of five child processes, why any child process is not getting exited before ```wait()``` call?

Comment: Recommeding to read the documentation to `wait()`.

Comment: `wait` will not return in the parent until a child exits.  Why do you think no child is exiting before `wait`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon exit, the child leaves an exit status that should be returned to the parent. So, when the child finishes it becomes a zombie.

Whenever the child exits or stops, the parent is sent a `SIGCHLD` signal.
The parent can use the system call `wait()` or `waitpid()` along with the macros `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` with it to learn about the status of its stopped child.

If the parent exits, than you can see your children still as zombie processes (unwaited children ).

`wait()` just tells you which child exited so you can get the exit code. If you have more children running, then of course, others could have terminated in the meantime as well.

If you don't care about the exit status, then `wait()` is just fine, but you still have to wait on all children you started.